# Qt Example: com.qmlqb.qmlcomponents is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am working through an example in the book, "Getting Started with Qt Quick", and the example code has a MainForm.ui.qml with the following import:

> import com.qmlqb.qmlcomponents 1.0

When I try to run, I receive this error:

> qrc:/MainForm.ui.qml:4 module "com.qmlqb.qmlcomponents" is not installed

What is this import? How can I install it?

Comment: This library is not part of Qt, I think the author has created his library so I recommend writing and telling you the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I learned what was going on. I was attempting to access a C++ class within Qt, and it was registered with the following statement in main.cpp:

> qmlRegisterType  ("Com.qmlqb.qmlcomponents",1,0,"MyClass");

The [documentation on qmlRegisterType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) specifies that the first argument is the name for the library in which the type will be imported.

So, I then tried to import that library in MainForm.ui.qml, with the following import statement, which threw an error:

> import com.qmlqb.qmlcomponents 1.0

As you can see, the capitalization is different between the two. After fixing that, everything was fine :)